# Page publishing failing in child Publication, but works fine in parent Publication

Tags: publishing, 2011-sp1

I have a Page that is inherited from a parent Publication as is. The Page gets successfully published from the parent Publication. However, while tying to publish the same Page from the child Publication it fails with "Object reference not set to the instance of an object error".

I am not sure what is wrong. Where do I start looking? Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Post stacktrace from event viewer and preview your page in Template builder to see which of TBB failing

Comment: Can you post more with regards what you have tried and what the results are. Did you preview the child page and it previewed OK (the HTML rendered as expected)? Did you check the logs, have you configured the publish targets correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved..!!!
Thanks a lot to all of you for your help.
In the child publication, the linked component fields of a component, were not having any data and there was no null check in place for the same. That was the reason of the page publish failing with "Object reference not set.." message.

Comment: Could you accept the appropriate answer please? That way other users can see that the question has been answered and needs no further attention.

Answer (score 1):

This error message is a null reference exception from TOM or the TOM.NET API.  Unfortunately, it is also very difficult to quickly track down the error and you'll have to do some hunting around to find out.

If you are using Compound Templates, you can try to preview the Page Template with the page and see if you get a better error message with a line #.  You can also try to preview each of the Component Templates with the Component to see if it breaks.

Maybe if you are using WebDAV URLs to open a Components, and the WebDAV URL is hard-coded you would have an object without a value, and then when you try to access a property or method of that object you will have this error.

You would have the same with a URI reference, but I would guess all the URIs in the child are also in the Parent.

Finally, you might want to check if any of the templates are localized, since they could change the URI in the template and it would not find the object.